# How do I overwrite files locally? From master to my current working directory.

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

So I changed my directory to the correct location and I want to pull the changes and from the master to my working directory and overwrite what I have on my computer locally. How would I go about that?

Would I use "git checkout -- " to discard changes that I have locally and in with the files I wish to pull from the master?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your remote repo is called 'origin', you'll want to execute both of these commands:

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Be sure that you won't need any of your local changes before doing this, they will be gone for good if they don't match what's on the remote repo.